# Redux with $ObjMap

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

```js
const ACTION1: "ACTION1" = "ACTION1";
const ACTION2: "ACTION2" = "ACTION2";

const ACTIONS = {
  a: () => ({ type: ACTION1, payload: { num: 1 } }),
  b: () => ({ type: ACTION2, payload: { str: "A" } })
};

function reducer(action: $Values<$ObjMap<typeof ACTIONS, <R>(() => R) => R>>): string {
  switch (action.type) { // any | "ACTION1" | "ACTION2"
    case ACTION1:
      return "" + action.payload.num; // any | number
    case ACTION2:
      return "" + action.payload.str; // any | string
    default:
      ;(action.type: empty)
      return "";
  }
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAggYQCoEkDyA5AjALhgIkVUy3xgF4Cj1t8BuAKFElmswCY9Dkb2zLuxDH0ZNw0eD0wBlCjADeDGDACGeABQBKCgD4Y6+TCgBPAA4BTPG2wAaGKZXGANiBUATPIbABXALZ4sGABfYM0bJRgAIw1tcj0DIzNLSSF2OwdnVw8FGGgAJy44MhCgzQYg0QAzbzBgKABLcBg88zdvYHM89RU6xrA8ABIANRUnb3MIAB4BtEiAKwBZFVNJkwsQSpSaaTtJgCUddS1dGD3YvQOdTTx8+rAAcwUInobwCIgAd3qoYAALfRefQAdGtzNpFMplMAVBBzFsSDgIpDmuYoN48mACGQANSqXrgIEZFzuIE+XyMZHQ2Hw4SI5HKFpojFYmC4wEEolZIH5CmQtzmSoqbxOKB0+l0br4sAgpJ4cy+UwmMr0lFMzH4egRILlBhAA

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you, please, add what problems do you have with this code snippet, as there no flow errors in this snippet, so it hard to tell, what problem needs to be solved?

Comment: It resolves to union with `any`